# Registration check Mysql and Python

Tags: mysql-python

Hello the main problem that I am having when writing my code is that I was trying the make a registration check to see if an existing username already exists within my MySQL database however, whenever I try to check it results from the code I do not work at all

```
def register ():
Delete_screen()
global username_entry
global password_entry


Label(screen, text="Register", fg="black", font="none 24 bold").place(x = 760, y = 100, anchor = "center")
Label(screen, text = "Username*").place(x = 760, y = 150, anchor = "center")
username_entry = Entry(screen)
username_entry.place(x = 760, y = 175, anchor = "center")
Label(screen, text = "Password*").place(x = 760, y = 200, anchor = "center")
password_entry = Entry(screen)
password_entry.place(x = 760, y = 225, anchor = "center")
Button(screen, text = "Register", command = register_user).place(x = 760, y = 275, anchor = "center")
```

def register_user():

```
checkUsername = cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM user WHERE Username = %(Username)s", { "Username" : username_entry.get() })
print(checkUsername)



if checkUsername != 0:
    Label(screen, text = "Username already exists", fg = "red").place(x = 760, y = 300, anchor = "center")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the fetch methods to get the results:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM user WHERE Username = %(Username)s", { "Username" : username_entry.get() })
result = cursor.fetchone()
print(result)
```

If you're getting more than one row:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM user WHERE Username = %(Username)s", { "Username" : username_entry.get() })
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

BTW, for this use case, it may be better to try inserting it and catch the error (from the unique index); that way it'll handle the situation where two people try to register the same username at the same time.

Comment: Thank you however, the problem is that when comparing the results to username_entry.get() it does not equal to each other.

Comment: What does it equal, then?